# Incorrect argument labels in call to dynamically created multidimensional array

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I get the following errors when trying to create a multidimensioanl array dynamically:

Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'count:repeatedValue:', expected 'unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:')

Replace 'count: languageCount, repeatedValue' with 'unsafeUninitializedCapacity: languageCount, initializingWith'

and when I accept the auto correction suggestion, I then get:

Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type '(inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<_>, inout Int) throws -> Void'

which doesn't offer a fix button.

I don't understand these errors.

```swift
let numColumns = wordsInLanguageCount.max() ?? 0
let numRows = languageCount
var tableViewWords: [[Int]] = Array(count: languageCount, repeatedValue: [])
```

Comment: What's `languageCount`?

Answer (score 2):

For me the following runs without error on Swift5

```
let languageCount = 10    // This is an Int
var tableViewWords: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: languageCount)
```